# Is there a way to get sms details in android before sending the message?

Tags: android, sms

So basically I am looking to get the string inside of the sms message before the message is official sent... is there a way to do that... So for example I am texting my mom and say "hi" is there a way to pull that "hi" automatically send it off to a program and then send the message??

Answer (score 0):

Sorry there is no way to do so before sending SMS through native SMS composer, yes you can get SMS details but only after sending it.

Once you send SMS, system will be notified by using Broadcast receiver.

Yes Its possible to get message details if you define your own SMS layout and then sending SMS through it other than opening native SMS composer.